# SVN: Is the command "svn propget svn:mergeinfo" supposed to print something?

Tags: svn, merge

I want to find out what I merged with a while back (I simply forgot) and I was under the impression that "svn propget svn:mergeinfo" would print such info.

I am running this on a different machine from the one that I did the merge on.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The svn:mergeinfo property should be attached automatically to as few nodes as possible, preferably to the root (i.e. trunk, branches/xy ...) node only. You can check for all existing properties by

```
svn propget svn:mergeinfo -R .
```

If you still see nothing on the other machine you might need to update first ...

Answer (score 0):

A merge must not generate mergeinfos. Most of the times it does though.

Some cases where it does not save mergeinfo can be found e.g. here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html.